# system.out.print doesn't print any result when compiled with javac?

Tags: java

im totally newbie to java world and this my first 4 lines of codes and it give some error which i can't resolve

```
public class MyFirstClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int x = 3 ;
        String name = "Drik";
        x = x * 10 ;
        System.out.println("x is " + x);
    }
}
```

when i compiled this code with javac its creating the class file
but it have output in the screen
when i write the command to compile it it give another command code without printing the result

Comment: you shuld run it with "java" command too.. did you do that..?

Comment: @ntc no i didn't the book i used to study doesn't show that :)

Comment: @Fouad.. then do it.. java MyFirstClass.class

Comment: @ntc i did and this give me about 10 lines of errors :) i never though that a line of code will give all those errors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The javac tool reads class and interface definitions, written in the Java programming language, and compiles them into bytecode class files.

```
javac MyFirstClass.java
```

To run the class file, actually print the result you want, you have to run the bytecode class with java command like

```
java MyFirstClass
```

Comment: that i did but its not reading its giving error NoClassDefFoundError when call it with .class or even without

Comment: try like : at the command prompt 1. go to your path where java has been installed llike:  c:\program files\java\jdk1.6\bin 2. do the compilation with javac command with full package of your class like : c:\program files\java\jdk1.6\bin>javac d:\test\MyFirstClass 3. Then go to your class file location and do java like : d:\test>java MyFirstClass

Comment: its output the class in the same folder i put my app in and the problem that im totally newbie so i don't know what is CLASSPATH i found it point to a zip file called QTJava.zip and the full path is C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip

Comment: If you are totally new to java : do step by step from some sites like sun. do one thing i am putting some steps try to follow, I m sure you will be able to run. 1. download jdk1.6 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html 2. install the same, I think by default it will install to c:\programfiles..\jdk1.6\..   3. Then your env is ready. Now you can put your class at some location let's say at d:\test. 4. Then follow the above steps which I have mentioned. I m sure you will be able to run.

Comment: that its exactly what i did and here is a screen shoot for the error http://i55.tinypic.com/2wntnkl.jpg

Comment: Is the class complete by itself, or you have mentioned any package name to it ?

Comment: i didn't mentioned any package name to it class just like it is in above code wrote it then javac to get the class file and tried to run it with java and that its the errors i got within the screen shiir

Comment: @Fouad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2754/discussion-between-swagatika-and-fouad)

Answer (score 1):

`javac` does not run the file, it will compile your `MyFirstClass.java` file to bytecode, creating `MyFirstClass.class` file.

Then you can actually run the program by doing:

```
java MyFirstClass
```

Comment: you run the program by doing `java MyFirstClass` .. the .class will give you a noclassdeffounderror.

Comment: @Fouad -- Make sure that the class file you are running is in the classpath. Do this `java -cp . MyFirstClass`

Answer (score 0):

1. open your cmd
2. run java -version
   if you have an output - your java is installed ok. If not - install java correctly (install the jdk, define JAVA_HOME env. variable + define the path environment variable to look at %JAVA_HOME%\bin)
3. move to the directory where the *.class file exists (make sure its really there :) )
4. run the following command:
   java MyFirstClass 
   This should work
   If it doesn't for some reason, try the following instead:
   java -cp . MyFirstClass

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

hey may be there is issue with the classPath.. if you are using windows type **set** in command prompt (**export** in ubunto) it shows list of pathvariables, check for **classPath** variable. if its not pointing to the directory where in you have saved your class, use **set** command to set its path. hope this will work.

Comment: yes this is very helpful but the question is do i have to set the classpath to the same app path ?

Comment: @Fouad..check where its actually saving the class file. set your classPath till that directory. if you are using packages then set it till the directory which has the root package directory..

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have traversed to till the directory where your file exists.
2. Then compile the file as javac .java. Check if class file has been generated.
3. Once it generates, run it as **java MyFirstClass**
4. It should execute the program.
5. Please check the classpath of 'JAVA' in environment variables once.